# Best way to present the ambiguous extra hour when winter time begins

Tags: timezone, dst

What is the standard way to present the ambiguous extra hour when winter time begins?

So far i used localized time formats to display and parse dates and times. E.g. `1. January 2014, 15:27`.

I'm using location based time zones like "Europe/Berlin".
And i can't just change to plain GMT offsets because i do need to perform calculations on the dates. Otherwise i would get the wrong absolute time when moving across DST change dates.

All this works fine except for the one hour at the end of DST (e.g. October 26th 2014, 2am-3am) which occurs twice. I need to present it in a way that i can later parse again.

Is there a stadardized format? Do i just add a custom symbol? Do i use the GMT offset additionally to the geographic time zone? And how do i know *when* to use this special format - because i don't want to print it all the time, since it's redundant most of the year.

Comment: The time zone offset information is *never* redundant. There is always an offset, and without documenting you have incomplete information. A date-time without a time zone offset is like a text file without a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or other documentation about its [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a standard that combines *everything*.  The closest you can get is with two fields.  One which would be an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)/[RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) Date+Time+Offset, and another which would be the [IANA](http://iana.org/time-zones)/[Olson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) time zone.

Depending on your platform, you may have a single *object* that represents both, such as a `DateTime` in [Joda-Time](http://joda.org/joda-time/) or a `ZonedDateTime` in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/).  But there is no standardized representation of this as a string.

Here are some that I have seen though:

- Two completely separate strings:

  ```
  "2014-10-26T02:00:00+01:00"
  "Europe/Berlin"
  ```
- One concatenated string, space separated:

  ```
  "2014-10-26T02:00:00+01:00 Europe/Berlin"
  ```
- One concatenated string with a space and using parentheses:

  ```
  "2014-10-26T02:00:00+01:00 (Europe/Berlin)"
  ```
- One concatenated string without any space, but with square brackets:  *(thanks Basil)*

  ```
  "2014-10-26T02:00:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]"
  ```
- As JSON, with some predetermined field names:

  ```
  {
      value: "2014-10-26T02:00:00+01:00",
      zone: "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  ```
- As XML, with some predetermined attribute names:

  ```
  <TimeStamp Value="2014-10-26T02:00:00+01:00" Zone="Europe/Berlin" />
  ```
- As XML, with some predetermined element names:

  ```
  <TimeStamp>
      <Value>2014-10-26T02:00:00+01:00</Value>
      <Zone>Europe/Berlin</Zone/>
  </TimeStamp>
  ```

Any of these would be acceptable.  Pick the one that fits your situation, or adapt to something similar.

Regarding your question:

> ... how do i know when to use this special format ...

When you're recording an event that has already passed and cannot be changed, then you do not need to store the time zone.  The date+time+offset value alone is sufficient.  Otherwise, you need both.

Comment: The ISO format will tell me the moment in time (i.e. absolute time) and the IANA time zone will tell me how to handle calculations. Check. In short: i _have_ to include the offset to get the right time. Tested this with my parser and it works.
So the only question remaining is when to add the offset - because it's not a technical format, it's an editable GUI field. And i have to keep it short and readable. I can make the offset optional for parsing. But i still have to do the roundtrip (format stored data -> GUI -> parse data) and get the same value. I could test that when formatting...

Comment: The approach I usually use is as follows:  1) Get the time zone, usually in in user's profile settings somewhere global for the app, but possibly at the time of entry if required.  2) Prompt for date and time only.  3) Validate the input. 4) If it is invalid because it falls into a spring-forward DST period, then prompt the user something like "2:30 AM is invalid on this day."  5) If it is ambiguous because it falls into a fall-back DST period, then prompt the user something like "Which did you mean? 1:30 AM PDT (-7) or 1:30 AM PST (-8)?"

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21343036/642706) is correct and insightful.

## Java 8 & java.time.*

Let me add another to his list, from the new [java.time.* classes](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). These new classes are inspired by Joda-Time but are re-architected.

The default used by [java.time.ZonedDateTime](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is one concatenated string using square brackets around the time zone name and no spaces.

> 2014-10-26T13:49:48.278+01:00[Europe/Berlin]

---

@MattJohnson Feel free to merge this answer's content with yours if you wish.